# Spring 3.2.9; Tiles 2.0.7; Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

I'm trying to update our Spring project from 2.5.6 to 3.2.9.  We're using Tiles 2.0.7, and Spring Web Flow 2.3.  I'm stuck on an error that doesn't have a relevant solution in Stack Overflow or in other forums:
(Partial Stacktrace):

```
####<Apr 13, 2015 4:11:53 PM GMT-06:00> <Warning> <HTTP> <xxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com> <managedserver1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1428963113472> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lkTimeZones' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webObjectBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified.  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lkTimeZones' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webObjectBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
```

My applicationContext.vxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"                           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->
<bean name="jndiName" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="wevsplatds"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">
                weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName" ref="jndiName"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="dataSource"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Here's an excerpt from my webObjectBeans.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Formatting Beans -->
<bean name="loc" class="java.util.Locale">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String"
                     value="${languageId}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String"
                     value="${countryId}"/>
</bean>
<bean name="dateFormatSymbols" class="java.text.DateFormatSymbols">
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.Locale" ref="loc"/>
</bean>
<bean name="calendarTagDateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="MM-dd-yyyy"/>
</bean>
<bean name="monthlyLinksDateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="MMMM yyyy"/>
</bean>
<bean name="weeklyLinksDateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="MMM d"/>
</bean>


<!-- System Beans -->
<bean id="cmAlarms" 
      class="com.fruit.apples.alarm.Alarm"
      p:errorCode="CALLMGRWEB001"/>

<!-- Collections Beans -->  
<bean id="lkTimeZones" class="com.fruit.apples.customer.webdisplay.collections.LkTimeZones"
      init-method="loadActiveTimeZones"
      p:timeZonesDao-ref="lkTimeZonesDAO" />
<bean id="lkHelps"
      class="com.fruit.apples.customer.webdisplay.collections.LkHelps"
      init-method="loadActiveHelp" 
      p:lkHelpDao-ref="lkHelpDAO" />
<bean id="lkActivityAreas"
      class="com.fruit.apples.customer.webdisplay.collections.LkActivityAreas"
      init-method="loadActiveActivityArea"
      p:lkActivityAreaDAO-ref="lkActivityAreaDAO" />
```

And finally a section from LkTimezonesDAO.java:

```
package com.fruit.apples.customer.dao;

import com.fruit.apples.customer.webdisplay.LkTimeZone;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;

public class LkTimezonesDAO extends CustomerWebDaoImpl
   {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2367566965661648309L;

/**
 * getAllLkTimeZones retrieves all data for LkTimeZoneObjects. The data
 * populates the List Object passed to this method with LkTimeZone objects
 * as appropriate for the data retrieved
 *
 * @param  listToLoad  the List Object to be populated
 */
public void getAllLkTimeZones( List<LkTimeZone> listToLoad )
{
    listToLoad.clear();
    JdbcTemplate jcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jcTemplate.queryForList(queries.get( "allLkTimezonesQuery" ) );

    if ( (rows!=null) || (0 < rows.size() ) )
    {
        for ( Map<String,Object> row : rows )
        {
            listToLoad.add( initializeLkTimeZone( row ) );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * getAllLkTimeZones retrieves only active data for LkTimeZoneObjects. The
 * data populates the List Object passed to this method with LkTimeZone
 * objects as appropriate for the data retrieved
 *
 * @param  listToLoad  the List Object to be populated
 */
public void getActiveLkTimeZones( List<LkTimeZone> listToLoad )
{
    listToLoad.clear();
    JdbcTemplate jcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jcTemplate.queryForList(queries.get( "activeLkTimezonesQuery" ) );

    if ( ( rows != null ) || ( 0 < rows.size() ) )
    {
        for ( Map<String,Object> row : rows )
        {
            listToLoad.add( initializeLkTimeZone( row ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `LkTimezonesDAO`

```
JdbcTemplate jcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
```

You are instantiating `jdbcTemplate` yourself with the `new` keyword, how does it know about `dataSource`?

You should inject the one defined in context via `@Autowired` or `xml`.

Comment: Okay, I injected `@Autowire` instance of data source like this:
`private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private DataSource setDataSource() {
      return dataSource;
}`
This still returns the same error: `nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified.`

Comment: You don't need to inject the `DataSource` itself, you need to inject `JdbcTemplate`. JdbcTemplate needs `dataSource`, which you've configured in xml. You need `@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;` in `LkTimezonesDAO` and remove line which instantiates `JdbcTemplate` with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Please see my answer above for my last attempt.  Sorry for the confusion, my comment was too long (1747+ characters).

Comment: `@Autowired` does not work on methods, it should be on field only.
You got `NullPointerException` because most likely you're initializing `LkTimezonesDAO` with the new keyword, which again you should `@Autowire` it somewhere or get manually from Spring Context. You do not instantiate beans which are managed by Spring.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not initializing LkTimesDAO with the new keyword. I'm instantiating the bean in 'webDataAccessBeans.xml' :
`<bean id="lkTimeZonesDAO" parent="abstractCustomerDao"      class="com.att.callmanager.customer.dao.LkTimezonesDAO">`  and connected to 'LkTimeZones' in 'webObjectBeans.xml' and collections of DAOs in 'buisnessObjectBeans,xml'.

Comment: Can anyone else be more specific on how to `@Autowire` the JdbcTemplate class in all of the DAOs?  I've tried Bing, Google, Yahoo and others.  Most answers involve Maven which wasn't included in my project.  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I injected the `dataSource` into the DAO file, but came up with a 'NullPointerException' error again.  Unfortunately I believe part of the problem is that I have 14 different DAO files connecting various queries to the database.  One instance I connected to LkTimezonesDAO.java via `@Autowire` like so:

```
`import javax.sql.DataSource;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 /**
  * ClmgrLkTimezonesTableDAO is a data access object specifically designed to
  * retrieve and set LkTimeZone object data.
  *
  */
  @Service("timeZonesService")
  @Repository
  public class LkTimezonesDAO extends CustomerWebDaoImpl
  {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 2367566965661648309L;
      private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;

      @Autowired
      public void init(DataSource dataSource) {
         this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
      }
```

``
     Here is a sample stack trace:

```
`####<Apr 21, 2015 11:50:30 AM GMT-06:00> <Warning> <HTTP>            <xxxxxxxx.xx.xxx.xxx.com> <managedserver1> 
 <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1429638630468> 
 <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lkTimeZones' defined in ServletContext resource 
 [/WEB-INF/webObjectBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lkTimeZones' defined in ServletContext resource 
 [/WEB-INF/webObjectBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:376)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
```

Comment: Okay, my attempts at `@Autowired` the JdbcTemplate instance from applicationContext.xml to DAO is coming up with NPE (NullPointerException) errors.  Does anyone need to see more code in order to find a solution?